# Windows firewall might be blocking web socket port

Tags: windows, firewall

I am trying to listen to music on the following music streaming service:

https://turntable.fm/

When I visit the site and go to me and my friends room to listen to music, the websocket appears to fail connection (in Firefox and Chrome) and after about 30 seconds I get the following error message from the website:

> Could not connect to turntable. Please try again. If you still cannot connect, you might have a firewall blocking your connection. (8080)

I am using a work laptop so it's highly possible that the Firewall is blocking the websocket. Here is the URL to the websocket that it fails to connect to:

wss://chat1.turntable.fm:8080/socket.io/websocket

Is it possible to configure the firewall to allow this connection? The computer uses windows firewall and a VPN (not sure if that makes a difference)

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: "Is it possible to configure the firewall to allow this connection?" - What is more likely is the VPN is blocking the website.  I would be shocked if the firewall was specifically configured to block port 8080; Typically unencrypted http traffic is on port 80 which tells me you are going through a proxy and/or vpn in order to scan and block unwanted traffic.  Without bein an Administrator you won't be able to make Windows Firewall configuration changes anyways.

Comment: You are correct that it is the VPN, I tried disabling it and it worked. Is there anyway I could get around this by still being connected to my VPN?

Comment: Configure the VPN to allow the connection.

Comment: Is that something I can do on my machine?

Comment: No; The VPN more than likely is blocking the connection, the only thing you could do in theory, is NOT use the VPN